# HTTP output in Logstash with JSON

Tags: logstash

In Logstash, when a log of a certain time is processed, I want Logstash to do an HTTP POST to a webserver, sending JSON.   However, it's giving me errors and won't start logstsh.  I'm assuming it doesn't like the ' around the JSON data that is part of the message.  FOOIP is a variable with the IP  Address found in the Log.  Any help would be great

Logstash config file....

```
output{
    if [type]=="FOO"{
       http {
       format=>"json"
       http_method=>"post"
       url=>"http://192.168.1.10/bar"
       message=>"{'target':{'IPAddress':'"%{FOOIP}"},'commandName':'Test'}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here? I see you have a config file - is it working? If not what's the error message? Also a sample log file line for debugging logstash is highly recommended.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  I forgot the "I'm getting errors when trying to startup logstash, it doesn't like the syntax for the 'message'".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `http` output when format is set to `json` will post the whole event in `json` to the web service (so it will ignore the message piece you have set).  So if you want it to work with the exact message that you are setting, try changing to format=message.

Comment: Thanks, that got Logstash running.  However, 15 seconds after it starts, it crashes with an error with the HTTP plugin.  "NameError: uninitialized constant HTTP".   I am assuming I have to run logstash with the "web" command?  >bin/logstash agent -f log.conf web"

Comment: I needed to upgrade to the latest version of logstash (1.4.2) and was able to get it running.